# J Panel's Childs are visible while setting visibility of J Panel to false, how to make childs invisible?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I am having a serious problem from last 2 to 3 hours, I am making java software(University record management System 
`URMS`) using Netbeans,[You can see the image from the link provided, I have made a tab pane, In which I added 5 panels, In the `Add Data` Tab, I have placed a `combo box` and 6 panels(Each panel's visibility is handled by the `combo box's` each item), Before getting this error shown in the image provided in the 2nd link, I had edited the property of panels as

```
opaque = set 
Layout = null Layout
panels position was like coins or cards place one on the face of another
```

which was working fine for me, as you can see the image from first link as shown below][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cexCD.jpg) [but when i edited the properties as

```
opaque = Unset 
Layout = null Layout
panels position was like coins or cards place one on the face of another
```

The panels background color is not visible but the childs are still visible, you can see it in 2nd link, which is making the text worst][2], how can i set the visibility OFF for the childs also, Please Guys Help me and take me out from this situation, I'll be very thank full to u.enter [FirstImage][2] [SecondImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cexCD.jpg)

***EDIT1:***
Here is the code

```
private void SelectionBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    switch (SelectionBox.getSelectedIndex()) {
        case 0:
            StudPanel.setVisible(true);
            MarkSheetPanel.setVisible(false);
            PaymentPanel.setVisible(false);
            DepartPanel.setVisible(false);
            CoursePanel.setVisible(false);
            EmpPanel.setVisible(false);
            break;
        case 1:
            StudPanel.setVisible(false);
            MarkSheetPanel.setVisible(false);
            PaymentPanel.setVisible(false);
            DepartPanel.setVisible(false);
            CoursePanel.setVisible(false);
            EmpPanel.setVisible(true);
            break;
        case 2:
            StudPanel.setVisible(false);
            MarkSheetPanel.setVisible(false);
            PaymentPanel.setVisible(false);
            DepartPanel.setVisible(false);
            CoursePanel.setVisible(true);
            EmpPanel.setVisible(false);
            break;
        case 3:
            StudPanel.setVisible(false);
            MarkSheetPanel.setVisible(false);
            PaymentPanel.setVisible(false);
            DepartPanel.setVisible(true);
            CoursePanel.setVisible(false);
            EmpPanel.setVisible(false);
            break;
        case 4:
            StudPanel.setVisible(false);
            MarkSheetPanel.setVisible(false);
            PaymentPanel.setVisible(true);
            DepartPanel.setVisible(false);
            CoursePanel.setVisible(false);
            EmpPanel.setVisible(false);
            break;
        case 5:
            StudPanel.setVisible(false);
            MarkSheetPanel.setVisible(true);
            PaymentPanel.setVisible(false);
            DepartPanel.setVisible(false);
            CoursePanel.setVisible(false);
            EmpPanel.setVisible(false);
            break;
        default:
            StudPanel.setVisible(false);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: Sorry The Second Link is here as I m no able to provid more than 1 links due to below than 10 reputation
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQQ14.jpg
OK I'll observe it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your components (JLabels, JTextFields, etc) are properly set into each JPanel then you should have no trouble setting the visibility of each JPanel dependent upon which JComboBox item was selected.

Let's assume we have 3 JPanels named: jPanel1, jPanel2, and jPanel3. In each of these JPanels we have Swing components like JLabels and JTextFields (or whatever) contained within each JPanel. The we have your JComboBox (named jComboBox1) which has three string items contained within it ("Pane 1", "Pane 2", and "Pane 3").

When your JFrame form is initialized we hide our JPanels using the **JPanel.setVisible()** method:

```
jPanel1.setVisible(false);
jPanel2.setVisible(false);
jPanel3.setVisible(false);
```

Now in your JComboBox **ActionPerformed** event you will have code something like this:

```
jPanel1.setVisible(false);
jPanel2.setVisible(false);
jPanel2.setVisible(false);
switch (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()) {
    case "Pane 1":
        jPanel1.setVisible(true);
        break;
    case "Pane 2":
        jPanel2.setVisible(true);
        break;
    case "Pane 3":
        jPanel3.setVisible(true);
        break;
}
```

You will most likely need to set location for each JPanel and some other minor properties as well to ensure proper layout. When you run your application the JPanels specified during initialization are all invisible. When you select the Pane you want to see from the JComboBox then the **ActionPerformed** event is fired which in turn hides all panes (should any be visible from a previous selection) then makes the Pane selected visible.

From this example you should be able to apply the concept to you own situation.

Comment: Yes You have assume the code awsomely but my code is little bit change, u can observe it in the code, Sorry for not attaching the code, now in edit1 i have attached the code u can see it from my question description

Comment: The text is still going worst please guide me what I do

Comment: Your code works for me, It helps alot, one thing i also do that i attached this code

            `StudPanel.setVisible(false);
            MarkSheetPanel.setVisible(false);
            PaymentPanel.setVisible(false);
            DepartPanel.setVisible(false);
            CoursePanel.setVisible(false);
            EmpPanel.setVisible(false);`

in Constructor below initComponent method

Comment: Yes...exactly. You need to do this so that all your panels are invisible when the Form opens. :)

Answer (score 1):

you didn't provide any code. 
on the combo-box popup will become invisible event, call the repaint() methods.

Update:

Thank you now providing the code, now, can you check by calling the repaint(); at the end.

```
private void SelectionBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    switch (SelectionBox.getSelectedIndex()) {
        case 0:
            StudPanel.setVisible(true);
            MarkSheetPanel.setVisible(false);
            PaymentPanel.setVisible(false);
            DepartPanel.setVisible(false);
            CoursePanel.setVisible(false);
            EmpPanel.setVisible(false);
            break;
        case 1:
            StudPanel.setVisible(false);
            MarkSheetPanel.setVisible(false);
            PaymentPanel.setVisible(false);
            DepartPanel.setVisible(false);
            CoursePanel.setVisible(false);
            EmpPanel.setVisible(true);
            break;
        case 2:
            StudPanel.setVisible(false);
            MarkSheetPanel.setVisible(false);
            PaymentPanel.setVisible(false);
            DepartPanel.setVisible(false);
            CoursePanel.setVisible(true);
            EmpPanel.setVisible(false);
            break;
        case 3:
            StudPanel.setVisible(false);
            MarkSheetPanel.setVisible(false);
            PaymentPanel.setVisible(false);
            DepartPanel.setVisible(true);
            CoursePanel.setVisible(false);
            EmpPanel.setVisible(false);
            break;
        case 4:
            StudPanel.setVisible(false);
            MarkSheetPanel.setVisible(false);
            PaymentPanel.setVisible(true);
            DepartPanel.setVisible(false);
            CoursePanel.setVisible(false);
            EmpPanel.setVisible(false);
            break;
        case 5:
            StudPanel.setVisible(false);
            MarkSheetPanel.setVisible(true);
            PaymentPanel.setVisible(false);
            DepartPanel.setVisible(false);
            CoursePanel.setVisible(false);
            EmpPanel.setVisible(false);
            break;
        default:
            StudPanel.setVisible(false);
            break;
    }

repaint();
}
```